# How to display a popup Window just when a browser is started running from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, popup

I want to popup a window on Internet explorer windows 10 from nodejs.
I did research on google but I found only the **window-popup**, **popup** packages but it is throwing me error something like this **ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at windowPopup**
Even after installing the packages thrpugh npm.
I am doing this on **WebStorm** ide.

```
exec(`START iexplore.exe`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
if (err) {
    throw err
}

console.log('stdout', stdout)
console.log('stderr', err)
});
```

var popup = require('window-popup').windowPopup;

What is the correct way to do this, please help me out where I am going wrong.
Thanks.